# python 3 count boolean value per columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I using pandas, I would like to know if there is a way to count boolean values per columns:

Here is my code :

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'Col1': [True, True, True, False, False, False ],
    'Col2': [False, False, True, False, True, False  ]}


df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I would like to have a result like this :

```
       Col1  Col2
True     3     2    
False    3     4
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using `apply` with `pd.Series.value_counts`:

```
df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts)
```

Output:

```
       Col1  Col2
False     3     4
True      3     2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
for col in df.columns:
    print(df[col].value_counts())
```

But the output would not be similarly formatted, though it would get the needed answer.

```
True     3
False    3
Name: Col1, dtype: int64
False    4
True     2
Name: Col2, dtype: int64
```